# Logs for debugging a GAE app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I've deployed an application to GAE and now I get "404 NOT_FOUND" error.

Where I can find out the detailed information about this error (stack trace) ?

In "Logs" and "Admin logs" I didn't find anything useful.

Note: By "logs" I do not mean logs for site visiting statistics.

Update: Now I managed to get rid of the 404 error. However, now I get another logging related error:

> [s~project-control-center/1.352785038340247795].: 
>   Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running this locally or on the Google App Engine? If locally , the terminal from which you launched the appserver should give you some details about the error.

Comment: Sorry didn't read the question properly. I see that on the first line now. Do you see this error when running the application locally? That might be the easiest way to debug the error, rather than remotely on the GAE infrastructure.

Comment: I'm migrating an existing Vaadin application to GAE. And yes, before migration it worked via "mvn jetty:run".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been some problems recently with displaying the logs in the admin console.  You can try downloading the logs:

- [Log Download Docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Logs)

Set `--severity=0` to get the DEBUG level.

Comment: appcfg --severity=0 request_logs myapp/war mylogs.txt returns a log file with request data (same as in "Logs" in the GAE admin console), but no stack trace.

Comment: To me that would indicate that there is no logging being generated for the 404.  Does it work locally?

Comment: It's a Vaadin application and before migration to GAE it worked perfectly (via "mvn jetty:run").

Comment: When running locally, are you using the GAE SDK?

Comment: 1) See above - now the 404 error is removed. 2) No, I don't use GAE when running locally and I don't intend to do so (because a) it would make the building process even more complex than it is and b) the documentation of GAE tells that local GAE and real GAE behave differently in some situations).

Comment: Although the local SDK server does not replicate the production environment exactly, it does get pretty close and I recommend you use it.  Is your logger trying to write to a file?  You can't do that on GAE.

Answer (score 1):

All requests are logged, but the default view is to show only logs with error messages. Click on 'Show: All requests' on the top of the logging page to show all requests.

There's unlikely to be a stacktrace for a 404 not found message, because no error occurred - the URL you attempted to fetch simply didn't exist.

Comment: See my update - now the 404 error is removed, but I still don't have meaningful logs because the logback class cannot be instantiated. It is contained in the dependencies (logging works perfectly, when running the app in Jetty).

Comment: @Dmitri Are you trying to customize logging in some way? You don't need to manually configure logging at all on App Engine.